# Using post/get on Yii 2.0

Tags: php, rest, api, yii

Im new to knew and believe this is quite simple to do, but I already read some documentation and cant find a way to do it. I have a request to a RestApi that takes a parameter that's a food's name. I want to be able to, using a text box, input that food's name and use it on the request, in the same page. Here is what I have so far:

```
<form method="GET">
<input type="text" name="to_search">
<button>Search</button>
</form>
<p></p>

<?php

use \Adcuz\FatSecret\Client;

$request = Yii::$app->request;

$get = $request->get();

$food =  $get ['to_search'];

$consumerKey = "xxxxxx";
$consumerSecret = "xxxxxx";

$cliente = new Client($consumerKey, $consumerSecret );

$search = $cliente->SearchFood($food);

$foods = $search->foods;

var_dump($foods);

?>
```

Comment: what's your question  ?

Comment: how can I send the value in my input to the $food in the php, and when I press the search button, I get the api answer to my request

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
<form method="GET">
<input type="text" name="to_search">
<button>Search</button>
</form>
<p></p>

<?php

use \Adcuz\FatSecret\Client;

//$request = Yii::$app->request;

//$get = $request->get(); 

// $food =  $get ['to_search'];

 //option 1
 $food = $_GET['to_search'];

//option2
$food = Yii::$app->request->get('to_search');
```